# Valgrind errors in context in C

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm getting this error but cant find the cause, it's a project and i can't really show the source code here, but I allocate memory like this:

```
if(!data_counter)
    lab=(ptr)malloc(sizeof(item));
else
    lab=(ptr)realloc(lab,sizeof(item)*(DC+1));
```

I keep getting this log in Valgrind, even though my code compiles and runs perfectly.
I have feeling that i reallocate the memory wrong.
Also the item in sizeof(item) is a struct with 4 fields

```
==18449==   
==18449== HEAP SUMMARY:  
==18449==     in use at exit: 352 bytes in 1 blocks  
==18449==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 14 frees, 4,416 bytes allocated  
==18449==   
==18449== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks  
==18449== Checked 69,180 bytes  
==18449==   
==18449== LEAK SUMMARY:  
==18449==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==18449==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==18449==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==18449==    still reachable: 352 bytes in 1 blocks  
==18449==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks  
==18449== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.  
==18449== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes  
==18449==   
==18449== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from  
==18449== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)  
==18449==   
==18449== 1 errors in context 1 of 3:  
==18449== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)  
==18449==    at 0x804B960: checkLabel (12.c:797)  
==18449==    by 0x8048B55: line_parser (12.c:132)  
==18449==    by 0x8048914: file_parser (12.c:108)  
==18449==    by 0x804C5CE: main (12.c:995)  
==18449==   
==18449==   
==18449== 1 errors in context 2 of 3:  
==18449== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)  
==18449==    at 0x804BC24: checkLabel (12.c:836)  
==18449==    by 0x8048B55: line_parser (12.c:132)  
==18449==    by 0x8048914: file_parser (12.c:108)  
==18449==    by 0x804C5CE: main (12.c:995)  
==18449==   
==18449==   
==18449== 2 errors in context 3 of 3:    
==18449== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)  
==18449==    at 0x804BE61: update_labl_adrr (12.c:883)  
==18449==    by 0x804C720: main (12.c:1014)  
==18449==   
==18449== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: You don't need to show proprietary source code to get help. But you *do need* to show a [mcve]. Otherwise there is not telling what is wrong.

Comment: A good first steep is running Valgrind with the `--track-origins=yes` option, as it states in the output - this will give you more information regarding the variable containing the uninitialised data.

Comment: Either `data_counter` or `lab` (or both) are not determinate at the time this code executes. That's what my crystal ball says, anyway. Judging by those errors, it's `data_counter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)` errors, these mean you have a condition that contains an uninitialized value.

This can be the condition in a `while`, `for`, `if` or `switch` statement. From the Valgrind backtrace, you can tell there's some flow control statement in `checkLabel` and `update_labl_adrr`, but since we can't see that code, it's hard to say anything else about it.

One common mistake when working with recursive structures (i.e. linked lists, trees etc.) is to not initialize the `next`/`child` pointers to NULL. This very often leads to the errors you posted. However, this is a complete guess since, again, we know nothing about your code.
There's no way to help out any further without, at the very least, knowing what's written in `checkLabel` and `update_labl_addr`